# Change Android Ethernet IP address from adb commands

Tags: android, networking, adb

My android device Ethernet IP is `192.168.1.52`.I tried to change Ethernet IP from adb using this :

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.60
```

so it changes my IP but when I turn off and on my eth0 as follows :

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 up
```

my IP returns back to `192.168.1.52`. How can I change it permanently?

Comment: If the IP address is setup hard coded in a service launch, or if it not a "persist.*" property, sure it will be reset at boot. You should first do a `getprop` on a `adb` shell to see how it is setup (is does not seem to be "persist" in your case), and then grep among services definitions (`*.rc ` files) to see which one is setting this up (it may also be a build time property).

Comment: @jbm can you please leave an example on comments?

Comment: Have you found a way to persist this?